# First row missing from the result set mysql_hook

Tags: airflow

Below code is used to fetch records from MySQL

```
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook

sql = "SELECT name, email FROM test.tbl_users"
mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_con', schema = 'test')
connection = mysql_hook.get_conn()
cur_dev = connection.cursor()
cur_dev.execute(sql)
source_list = cur_dev.fetchall()
print(source_list)
```

Expected output

[image]

Highlighted row is missing in the resultset

Am I missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by using `import pymysql`. Below is the updated code.

```
from airflow.models.connection import Connection
import pymysql    

conn = Connection.get_connection_from_secrets(conn_id='mysql_con')
conn_dev = pymysql.connect(
    user=conn.login,
    password=conn.password,
    host=conn.host,
    port=conn.port,
    database=conn.schema
)
cur_dev = conn_dev.cursor()
cur_dev.execute("SELECT name, email FROM test.tbl_users")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the hook functions? For most cases you don't need to use cursor. The hook has functions that do the work for you.
You can use : `get_records`, `get_first`, `get_pandas_df`, `run`, etc...

```
from airflow.providers.mysql.hooks.mysql import MySqlHook

sql = "SELECT name, email FROM test.tbl_users"
mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_con', schema = 'test')
records = mysql_hook.get_records(sql=sql)
```

If you do need the cursor then use `get_cursor()`

Comment: Updated code as suggested above using get_records. Still first row is missing.

Comment: Then you need to debug it with your own database as what you report isn't reproducible problem. You may have two tables with same name under different schemas or some other issue. I advise you to start a clean DB from fresh and see how it goes with it.